# Filtering legend of a Highcharts by only visible series

Tags: charts, highcharts

We are using Highcharts and have some complex charts with roughly 75 series within on chart.
The series are not used through the whole chart but only for range of three month. So we have about 15 series per year and the overall chart covers five years (makes roughly 15*5 = 75 series). However Highcharts displays all 75 charts within its legend. The goal is to minimize the legend to the visible series only. We are able to determine the related series in JS code and we tried to toggle the 'showInLegend' flags of the related series e.g.

```
chart.series[24].options.showInLegend = false
```

but without effect. We tried to redraw the chart using

```
chart.redraw()
```

but that has no effect...the legend remains unchanged.

So the questions are:

- is it possible to redraw the legend based on the updated showInLegend options?
- is there mechanism in Highcharts to dynamically updated the legend based on the visible series?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well just setting the `showInLegend` doesn't do the trick, there are some more hooks that need to be taken care of

Refer Halvor Strand's answer for a more recent way

---

### Old trick but still works

## To Add

```
item.options.showInLegend = true;
chart.legend.renderItem(item);
chart.legend.render();
```

## To Remove

```
item.options.showInLegend = false;
item.legendItem = null;
chart.legend.destroyItem(item);
chart.legend.render();
```

where, item can be a point or series

```
var item = chart.series[1];
```

**[Add Remove Legend Dynamically | Highchart & Highstock @ jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/MtwGc/)**

Comment: Working with the latest Highstocks version, however we are still on Highstocks 1.1.5....trying to upgrade

Comment: @user1833746 yes looks like it was added later

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Just used it to dynamically show labels for grouped series. The grouping by stack might be useful to @esaelPsnoroMoN for toggling the series for each year.
http://jsfiddle.net/59URa/9/

Comment: This answer is now outdated, see answer by Halvor Strand for how to do the same thing using newer Highcharts.

Answer (score 6):

You can set `showInLegend` as `false` when you create the chart.

```
{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
    showInLegend: false
}
```

[**demo1**](http://jsfiddle.net/z28G6/)

If you want to update it dynamically you can do the following.

```
options.series[1].showInLegend = false;
chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
```

You forgot to force chart to redraw.

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pKPpm/)

Or `chart.legend.allItems[1].destroy();` to remove the first one.

Comment: Just a minute apart my friend :)

Comment: @JugalThakkar Maybe seconds.

Answer (score 6):

This can now be solved without any hacks through the `Series.update` method ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update)). For example:

```
chart.series[0].update({ showInLegend: false });
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/ykho28vw/1/). The method signature is:

```
update(Object options, [Boolean redraw])
```

Where `options` are options for any regular `Series` object. You can optionally halt redrawing to change multiple options before redrawing.

Comment: This should be the new best answer.