# Filtering legend of a Highcharts by only visible series only in Export

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have an highchart and I create an export generated picture with the export function.

How can I make is so that the legend of the hidden series are not shown at all (I donøt want them greyed out) in the export?
I've tried this but it hides only the text, the symbol is still there.

```
    exporting: { //the export button
        type: 'image/jpeg',
         chartOptions: {
            legend: {
                enabled: true,
                itemHiddenStyle: {
                    display: 'none',
                }
            }
        }

    },...
```

I have also seen this answer: [Filtering legend of a Highcharts by only visible series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600741/filtering-legend-of-a-highcharts-by-only-visible-series)
but I need it done ONLY in export. That will remove it from the screen too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case you will have empty item, better is using load event and destroy series which are not visible.

```
exporting: { //the export button
        type: 'image/jpeg',
        chartOptions: {
            chart: {
                events: {
                    load: function () {
                          var chart = this;

                            $.each(chart.series,function(i,serie) {
                                if(!serie.visible) {
                                    serie.update({
                                        showInLegend:false
                                    });
                                }
                            });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    },
```

See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/DMJf5/3/