# How do I hide specific legend items?

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to hide specific legend items on my graph (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend). If I loop through the chart.legend.allItems and try to change a specific items visible property it does not effect the legend at all.

```
$.each(chart.legend.allItems, function() {
    this.visible = false;
});
```

How can I hide a specific legend item on my graph ?

Comment: Have you looked at the `showInLegend' property? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.showInLegend

Comment: @jlbriggs why don't you post this comment as an answer? It seems to be exactly what the OP needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found other solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13600741/filtering-legend-of-a-highcharts-by-only-visible-series)

```
var item = chart.series[1];
//hide serie in the graph
item.hide();
item.options.showInLegend = false;
item.legendItem = null;
chart.legend.destroyItem(item);
chart.legend.render();
```

EDIT:
Other solution for last version of highcharts:

```
$('#container').highcharts().series[1].update({ showInLegend: false });
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this is being made out to be more complex than it needs to be.

You can set `showInLegend` to `false` in your config options for the series.

If you need to do it programmatically, you can use `series.update()` to accomplish it dynamically.

Reference:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.showInLegend
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Series.update

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the `load event` - [Highcharts Doc](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load)

```
chart: {
        events: {
            load: function() {
                var myChart = this;

                $.each(myChart.series, function(index, serie) {
                    if(index === 2 ) { // hide serie
                        serie.hide();
                    }
                });
        }
    }
},
```

Here a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/ct16cnpa/)

Comment: Hi, thx for the prompt reply, I understand how to hide the series. I struggle to hide the legends(the labels next to the graph).

Comment: So, do you want to hide whole legend area, or some position from legend?

Comment: Hey, I want to hide just one legend item(one of the labels in the legend container/area), not the entire legend area.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to hide some labels you can add some css class to hide them according to some special feature of the series. I pass an example in which the series is hidden with empty data and also hide the label:

```
for (var i = 0; i < chart.series.length; i++) {
    if (chart.series[i].dataMax === 0) {
        chart.series[i].hide();
    }
}
$("#charContent").find('.highcharts-legend-item-hidden').each(function () {
    $(this).addClass('hidden');
});
```

In the css:

```
.highcharts-legend-item-hidden.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Maybe it's not a very clean solution but it works for me

Comment: Hi, the only issue with this solution is that the labels are positioned absolutely in the legend container. Hiding position absolute labels leaves empty gaps(where the hidden labels are positioned) in between the visible labels. Can you think of any way to hide the graph legends by manipulating the graph object ?

Comment: I post other answer with a better solution manipulating the legend object